# stop excel do-loop until

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns A and B with numbers as values.

- In C1 I want `=A1 + B1`
- In C2 I want `=A2 + B2`

and so on. I have written the following VBA code - while it works it adds "0" after the end of the last row in range.

Let's assume my last row is A10. It adds "0" in C11 when I run the code.
How do I prevent this?

```
Sub macro()

Dim R As Long
R = 1
Do
Cells(R, "C").Select
R = R + 1
ActiveCell.Formula = "=sum(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) & "," & 
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)    & ")"
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2))

End Sub
```

Comment: Try incrementing R at the end of the loop, just before Loop Until

Comment: @rick. It doesn't make any difference either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace your Until condition to the following string:

`Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2))`

That will check the right cell for being empty. The rest of your code should remain intact.

Comment: @Peter.Thank you very much..Your solution worked like charm with just one modification in my code but I still can't get the logic behind that.

Comment: @user1449596 your initial code checked for being empty the cell in column A for the SAME row where you put the formula in column C, i.e. you select sell C10, put formula there and check whether A10 is empty, and continue if it is not. If row 10 is the last where data is located in A & B - you'll receive one more loop which is unwanted. My offset checks the cell in column A but row is 1 step lower, i.e. for the above case it will check A11 which is empty, and therefore this is the end of cycle. Hope this helps with logic understanding!)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`Do Until` and `Do While` and `While`](http://www.databison.com/index.php/excel-vba-for-do-while-and-do-until-loop/).

If you really want to iterate over cells you may go ahead. But here a method using `Arrays`, this will by all means reduces any performance drops that you would get looping over cells...

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddToRigh()
Dim i As Integer
Dim vArr As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long

'--assume you are working on Sheet 1
LastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, Range("A1").Column).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim vArr(1 To LastRow)

For i = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
    vArr(i) = "=Sum(RC[-2]:RC[-1])"
Next i

'--output this entire array with formulas into column C
Sheets(1).Range("C1").Resize(UBound(vArr)) = Application.Transpose(vArr)

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm by no means an expert in vba, but you could do this:

```
Sub macro()


    Dim R As Long
    R = 1
    Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2))
        Cells(R, "C").Select
        R = R + 1
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=sum(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) & "," & 
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)    & ")"
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code gets same result. It adds "0" value i.e. formula "=sum(,)" after the last row in the range.

Comment: @Koenyn For `A1` selected before macro running you'll see "Application-defined or object-defined error" on cycle start (`Do While` line), since active cell is NOT yet **strictly** defined - you try to check it BEFORE selection. Sorry pal, but downvote. And yes, the above comment is also true.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not vba expert, I just though using a while loop is better than a do while loop. It's the exact same code, just with a while loop....

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd recommend a slightly different course of action, just to give you ideas :):

```
Sub macro()

    Dim found As Range

    Set found = Range("A:A").Find("*", after:=Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        Range(Range("A1"), found).Offset(0, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]+RC[-1]"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 upvoted to restore petty downvoting that appears to be linked to a now deleted post.

Comment: Thanks @brettdj, I appreciate the sentiment, though not `terribly` worried about the rep :).

Comment: Also @AnandKumar, I do owe you something of an apology; I realised before I went afk yesterday that your response was only one minute later than Koenyn's. I was sure I'd checked that before I downvoted you, but somehow I got it wrong. I wasn't all that endeared to apologise at the time, though. I understand you now cannot reverse your downvotes, and neither can I. I'd like to just say, everyone gets a little emotional and makes mistakes, no hard feelings from my end.

Comment: if the post is edited - by you or another - then the vote can be changed.

Comment: Good point, but now we're getting into fidgety territory, I'm just going to forget about it. Thanks again.